# Adding listview items to sqlyog

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

I'm making a Sales and inventory system at my school. I'd like to save the listview items to my database which is a MySQL sqlyog ultimate.

This is my connection and my code for saving listview to database but I get the error `Object variable or with block variable is not set`.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Module modconnector
    Public sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand
    Public sqlcon As New MySqlConnection
    Public sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Public sqlreader As MySqlDataReader
    Public strsql As String

    Sub connect()
        sqlcon.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;password= ;database=sais")
        sqlcon.Open()
    End Sub



    Sub savelistview()

        sqlcon.Close()
        connect()


        iCount = ListView1.Items.Count()
        If Not ListView1.Items.Count = 0 Then
            Do Until iLoop = ListView1.Items.Count
                With lvitem
                    lvitem = ListView1.Items.Item(iLoop)

                    strsql = "insert into transaction(prod_code,prod_description,prod_price,order,quantity,date) values('" _
    & .Items(0).Text & "','" _
    & .SubItems(1).Text & "','" _
    & .SubItems(2).Text & "','" _
    & .SubItems(3).Text & "','" _
    & .SubItems(4).Text & "','" _
    & .SubItems(5).Text & "','" _
    & Label26.Text & "')"
                    sqlcmd.CommandText = strsql
                    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon
                    sqladapter.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
                lvitem = Nothing
                iLoop = iLoop + 1

            Loop
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved!")
        sqlcon.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. There is a few things with your code that you must fix: **1)** The `Items` collection is zero-based, meaning that you must do `Do Until iLoop = ListView1.Items.Count - 1` or else you will get an `IndexOutOfRange` exception. **2)** I see no variable called `lvitem`, you must declare it and set it _before_ your `With` block: `Dim lvitem As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Item(iLoop)`. **3)** You should use SQL parameters instead of normal String concatenation, as it's possible to bug your system at the moment using what's called SQLInjection.

Comment: 4) you could use a DataGridView and DataAdapter so you need almost no code to update the db.  sqlyog is not a DB, BTW, just an admin UI for it.

Comment: hi and thank you for welcoming me in this organization. I follow the step 1 and 2 , but I can't understand the number 3. well I tried the number 1 and 2 and when I run it. if I have 1 row it says records saved but when I look at my database it didn't save. but if I have multiple row is says syntax error. can you teach me about the 3rd step?
to be honest I'm a beginner in programming and all the codes that I got is from the lesson in the school.